# How to test for Django Create and Update View

Tags: django, pytest, django-testing

To simplify, I cannot get the test to create or update the model that I have. I have written an `UpdateView` and a `CreateView`but I cannot get the test to work. Here are the views:

```
class InventoryCreateView(CreateView):

    model = BaseInventory
    context_object_name = 'item'
    fields = [
        'product_id',
        'name',
        'color_primary',
        'color_secondary',
        'category',
        'description',
        'gender',
    ]

    template_name = 'inventory_list/product_detail.html'

class InventoryUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = BaseInventory
    context_object_name = 'item'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'product_id'

    fields = [
        'product_id',
        'name',
        'color_primary',
        'color_secondary',
        'category',
        'description',
        'gender',
        ]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['colors'] = Color.objects.all()
        return context

    template_name = 'inventory_list/product_detail.html'
```

Here is the test that I have tried to create:

```
def test_create_inventory_view(self):
    """Test to see if inventory can be created"""
    form = {
        'product_id': 'vp12312',
        'name': 'Not a panda',
        'color_primary': self.color,
        'color_secondary': self.color,
        'category': BaseInventory.SHOES,
        'description': "Yellow panda",
        'gender': BaseInventory.MALE,
    }

    request = self.factory.post(InventoryCreateView, data=form)
    response = InventoryCreateView.as_view()(request)
    print(request)

    assert BaseInventory.objects.count() == 1
    assert 'inventory_list/product_detail.html' in response.template_name
    assert response.status_code == 302

def test_inventory_update_view(self):
    """Test for updating object"""
    item = BaseInventoryFactory(description='And everything you do')

    data = {
        'product_id': item.product_id,
        'name': item.name,
        'color_primary': item.color_primary,
        'color_secondary': item.color_secondary,
        'category': item.category,
        'description': 'Yeah they were all yellow',
        'gender': item.gender
    }

    request = self.factory.post('inventory_list:product-update',data,
                                kwargs={'product_id': item.product_id},
                                )
    response = InventoryUpdateView.as_view()(request, product_id=item.product_id)

    assert response.status_code == 302

    item.refresh_from_db()
    assert item.description == data['description']
```

both tests results in status code of `200` and the data is neither created nor updated. Is there something that I did wrong?

Comment: Check the form errors with `response.context['form'].errors`.

Comment: `self.factory.post(InventoryCreateView, ...)` and `self.factory.post('inventory_list:product-update', ...)` look incorrect - you should pass the actual URL (or use `reverse()`).

Comment: You may find it easier to use the request client instead of request factory. However some people will disagree with this suggestion because then it's an integration test for the URL and view instead of a unit test for the view.

Comment: @william Were you able to solve the issue? I am having the exact same problem where I am sending a post request using `django.test.Client` class but the number of objects of the model class is not incrementing.